# Do brassicas like to be transplanted deeper than the previous pot?

Tags: vegetables, transplanting, brassicas, broccoli, seedlings

I know that tomatoes should be transplanted deeper than they were in the previous pot.

When I'm potting up broccoli and cabbage, are they the same way? Can I bury part of the stem when I go from a 6-pack to a pot, or from a pot to the garden?

(I'm especially interested because my current batch of broccoli got a little leggy when I started them under the lights.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When I pot on (transfer to a larger pot) brassica seedlings, I always bury part of the stem, so that their lowest leaves are just above the surface of the soil. This encourages more root formation and gives them greater stability, particularly if they are leggy. So far, this method of transplanting has worked well for me, although I don't use it for the cucurbits (courgettes/ zucchini, squash etc), as these are fairly prone to stem rot. Of course, it's important to avoid over-watering and ensure that the compost/ soil is free-draining.

Answer (score 6):

This has worked for me for 20+ years, just like tomatoes. And of course, don't over water to avoid root rot.